# Can $\Omega$ be replaced with any open set of $\Bbb C$ in Theorem 5.2 and Theorem 5.3?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above pictures are from Stein's "Complex Analysis".

In Theorem 5.2 and Theorem 5.3, $\Omega$ is a region, I think it can be replaced with any open set of $\Bbb C$, can't it?

Comment: where does it say $\Omega$ is a region? and what is a region? is it just a simply connected, open set?

Answer (score 2):

Even if the theorems are stated for connected open sets you can apply them to connected components and conclude that they are valid for any open set $\Omega$. The conclusions are 'local' results so connectedness is irrelevant.  In fact the proofs themselves work for any open set $\Omega$. Note that any compact subset of $\Omega$ can be covered by a finite number of disks whose closures are contained in $\Omega$.